# shell_exec doesn't load environmental variables

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I have a function on admin panel that allows admins run CronJobs. I've implemented it through `shell_exec` function. There are two problems.

Problem 1
Script that executes `shell_exec` runs with user `rc` which I test with `echo get_current_user();` while the command executed with `shell_exec` is ran with `www-data` which I test by running `var_dump(shell_exec('whoami'));` and `var_dump(shell_exec('php -r "echo get_current_user()"'))`.

Problem 2
The `www-data` user doesn't recognise global environmental variables. I've added `APPLICATION_ENV=development` to `/etc/environment` which works fine because when I run `sudo -u www-data echo $APPLICATION_ENV` it displays  `development`. Running `var_dump(shell_exec('echo $APPLICATION_ENV'))` displays empty string.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What if you load your value with `getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')` before passing it to shell_exec??

Comment: can you describe your "admin panel" a bit more please? 
It reads like an already running web server process is launching the cron jobs (instead of a real cron daemon) and therefore not loading the global environment. a single service restart of nginx could help. Does  `putenv("APPLICATION_ENV=development");` before the `shell_exec` help?

Comment: @cyberbraina as a matter of fact it does help. Nginx isn't used when running the command as I directly run `php-cli`. Restarting nginx doesn't help. I don't think the admin panel matters but it's an `nginx` server runnig `php-fpm` without any special installations, just pure PHP with libs. The panel is purely in PHP. Even when running shell_exec directly I get the same results. Restarting the machine didn't help as well.

Comment: Regarding your second point, there is no such thing as "global environment variables"; every process has its own environment, inherited from its parent. `/etc/environment` is just a file that processes *might* read when they start up. So it's not entirely surprising that `sudo -u foo` and `php -r "shell_exec('foo');"` would end up with different environments.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with

```php
    var_dump(shell_exec('source /etc/environment && echo $APPLICATION_ENV'));
```

Comment: I'm still getting an empty string.